# I need a good italic font to pair with Impressum

Tags: typography, logo, font-recommendation

I'm looking for an elegant and not-too-busy italic font to pair with Impressum bold headline. See options I've tried already. Most seem to be too light, or too busy. All ideas welcome!
Thanks![image]

Comment: Are you looking for a free font or are you willing to pay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would try first: find a soft sans-serif, such as Optima. It feels gentle without serifs:

[image]

If you still want a serif font, I would go with something that has more contrast than the ones you are experimenting with. The block/slab-ish feel of the "first congregational" needs a little contrast in the serif font below, to not feel off. You *could* of course use the original font, impressum, as well. Here, I am suggesting something like Didot; or [**find similar fonts**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Theano-Didot) of the Italian style with a good deal of contrast between strokes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think a **Sans Serif** font works best. See samples below:

---

[image]

Comment: I agree with the above user, contrasting fonts usualy are very nice, ie thick bold fonts go good with thin fonts.

Answer (score -2):

try asking on http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ 
you usually get a response within an hour on their forums.

Comment: Your answer makes me wonder if you even read the question.

Comment: It's the quickest way to get matching fonts.

Comment: And you can even ask what font something is from an unidentified sample.

Comment: The fonts in the image are the ones they have already tried - therefore they know what fonts they are. So they don't need to do to WhatTheFont!